# Passing Value to PHP File

Tags: php, html, forms, get

i have tried following code in order to pass values to another php page, but i am not getting anything.

Filename : Send.html

```
<form id="form1" action="get.php" method="get">
<input name="search_name" type="text" id="search_name" size="20.5" height="45" border="#770074" >   
<select name="mydropdown" width="230" STYLE="width: 180px" size="0" "height: 200px">
<option value="All">All Categories</option>
<option value="Childrens Clothing">Childrens Clothing</option>
</select>
<img src="../img/search.jpg" width="70" height="45" border="0" align="left" usemap="#Map">
</form>

<map name="Map">
<area shape="poly" coords="5,35" href="#">
<area shape="rect" coords="-5,8,140,45" href="get.php">
</map>
```

Filename : get.php

```
<?php
$sname=$_GET['search_name'];
$cname=$_GET['mydropdown'];
echo $sname."<br>".$cname;
?>
```

Comment: How are you submitting the form? (There doesn't appear to be a submit button.)

Comment: Clicking on a link (i.e., on your image map) does not post a form.

Comment: Are you using the link in the image map? That's not going to work. You need a proper submit button or you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: You're using an image as the submit button, is that right? In that case, I think the issue is that the image link is just linking to `get.php`, and not actually submitting the form.

Comment: ow. how can image submit form.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();" src="../img/search.jpg" width="70" height="45" border="0" align="left" usemap="#Map">
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the `</form>` in `Send.html` add `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />` to add a proper submit button.

**Edit**
If you want to use an image, you can do:

```
<button type="submit"><img src="..." /></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<area shape="rect" coords="-5,8,140,45" onclick="document.form1.submit();">
```

This is a little edit on webarto's answer because I think you only want a specific area on image as your submit button.